# Prove that EF is the angle bisector of angle CED.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I would like some help getting started with this problem. My initial thought was to try to get that $\angle BEC \cong \angle AED$. From there I could say that $\overline{EF}$ is the angle bisector. However, I could not find a way to show some kind of similarity.

Note: $ABCD$ is a trapezoid. Diagonals intersect at $P$. The line through $P$ parallel to the bases intersects $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ at points $E$ and $F$, respectively. Right angles at $B$ and $A$. Prove that $\overline{EF}$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CED$.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zE11.png)

Comment: $\triangle BPC \sim \triangle DPA$, so their corresponding heights are in the same ratio as bases: $$\frac{BE}{AE} = \frac{BC}{AD}$$.

Comment: So I got that $\triangle BPC \sim \triangle DPA$ but I didn't think about the heights of those triangles. Thank you so much for the help!